# Would (theoretically) metastable solid metallic hydrogen even need an oxidizer?

Tags: fuel, hydrogen, monopropellant

In this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19947/12102) there is discussion of some research on the potential, future use of a solid metallic hydrogen phase that would be metastable at ambient pressure as a rocket propellant. The work is futuristic of course, but there is interest.

There is more information in the following questions and their answers:

[For the recently reported production (January 2017) of metallic hydrogen in the laboratory - what is the evidence exactly?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308155/83380)

[Are there predictions that hydrogen could remain metallic at ambient pressure?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308290/83380)

...and the BBC news article [Claim made for hydrogen 'wonder material'](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-38768683), quoted extensively in the second question.

Is the thinking is that it would be used as a monopropellant? Is it possible that the much heavier LOX needed for a conventional LH2/LOX engine would not even be needed?

Comment: heed my prediction. It will be exactly as all ultra-high-energy monopropellants: ludicrously explosive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the fuel would be used as a monopropellant because as soon as you excite the metallic hydrogen, it will be just H molecules which will quickly bond to each other to Form H2, creating mass amounts of energy. If you convert it back to molecular hydrogen, all the energy required to produce it is released. No burning would be necessary, it would just be the metallic hydrogen, which keep in mind would be denser than regular compressed cryogenic hydrogen, so it depends on how much you carry if it would weigh more or less, but no oxidizer would be needed. This source also explains some other key properties of metallic hydrogen if you are interested.

https://m.phys.org/news/2017-01-metallic-hydrogen-theory-reality.html

Comment: I haven't. I will do that now, in fact I am quite new I didn't see that

Comment: @uhoh Can the source be a video?

Comment: I always learn from him, he is very helpful in these matters.

Comment: Also, you can double check, but I am pretty sure the energy comes from the expansion itself, not from $2H \rightarrow H_2$. See [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/308301/83380) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/308156/83380) and [this](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/19949/12102) and all of the comments on those questions and answers for more info, and consider linking to them in your answer if either one helps.

Comment: I will look through them yes.

Comment: @uhoh It feels good to actually try to help people out

Comment: Yes, I will do that.

Comment: @uhoh: It comes from both, though in different ratios. (also splitting $H_2$ into monomolecular is caused through compression, so the reverse will cause extra expansion.)

Comment: @SF. OK I'll look into it but I'm pretty sure of two things, 1) 1 kg of neutral atomic hydrogen recombining to molecular hydrogen would only release a small fraction of the enegy that would be released here, 2) nobody knows how metastable solid metallic hydrogen would decompose, there are no reliable models for this, in fact there are no reliable models that can evens predict if it can be metastable in the first place. It will be hotter than the surface of the Sun, so I don't think there will be too much H2 , but I'll check.

Comment: @uhoh: ad 1) yes. ad 2) it will cool pretty fast. Still, per titular question, oxidizer would only reduce energy density and specific energy of the metal hydrogen used in bipropellant. You'd squeeze more energy per kg of hydrogen but less per kg of bipropellant. OTOH I wonder about using it in air-breathing engine. Big gain of thrust and good cooling simultaneously.

Comment: "...as soon as you excite the metallic hydrogen, it will be just H molecules which will quickly bond..." is worded a little poorly as it seems to imply that the hydrogen goes from metal to molecules to some other molecules (although I know what is meant and that H is not H_2). Rather say something like "...free H atoms which will quickly bond..." or "...H atoms which which will quickly form H_2 molecules..."