# Thrust value for a metallic hydrogen rocket-propelled spacecraft traveling on brachistochrone trajectories?

Tags: rockets, interplanetary, design-alternative

[image: Transit time nomogram, courtesy of Atomic Rockets]

Using the attached nomogram for computing brachistochrone trajectories to other bodies throughout our solar system, I am working with the assumption that this spacecraft travels with a constant acceleration of 1/3 g (right around where the acceleration column says "Mercury/Mars").

The second-to-the-left column of the nomogram lists various drive systems by their thrust capacity in newtons. Where on that column could I plug in a metallic hydrogen rocket?

Edit 1: What value in newtons would correspond to such a drive? You can pretend that you are a mad space scientist with access to experimental tech and near-unlimited funds.

Thanks.

Comment: Let me try this another way: If you know you get 1/3 g, and you know what the mass of your vehicle is, that tells you what the thrust is.  You have only revealed one of the three variables in the equation, so there is no way to figure out what the thrust is.

Comment: Edit 2: Understood, Organic Marble. Let's shotgun a bunch of possible values for the mass of the spacecraft. I'll go with 500 metric tons, 1 kiloton, 1.5 kt, 2 kt, 5 kt, 7.5 kt, and 10 kt.

Comment: What is a "metallic hydrogen rocket"?

Comment: somewhat related: [Brachistochrone variation for Earth-to-Mars Orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23088/12102) and Scott Manley's [Brachistochrone Trajectories For Spaceships Explained](https://youtu.be/toMnjO8aJDI)

Comment: @RussellBorogove possibly? [Has (theoretically) metastable metallic hydrogen been considered for use as a propellant?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19950/12102) and also [Would (theoretically) metastable solid metallic hydrogen even need an oxidizer?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19950/12102) answer links to Scott Manley's [Metallic Hydrogen - Most Powerful Rocket Fuel Yet?](https://youtu.be/nMfPNUZzG_Q)

Comment: It's still controversial whether metallic hydrogen has even been observed in the lab, so our current understanding of its properties are based on theoretical predictions. There is considerable disagreement in the theoretical predictions depending on method and whether you'd need another material to stabilize it. I'm not sure we know enough about it yet to say much about possible applications.

Answer (score 1):

You place it wherever you want.

Unlike [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse), thrust is not an inherent property of a fuel.  Every one of the entries in the second column refers to a specific engine design.  If you need more thrust, you just make the engine bigger (or add more of them), keeping in mind that doing so will increase your vehicle's fuel requirements and overall mass.